# python spider scrapy cannot launch the code

Tags: python, scrapy

I before used Selenium, but now client needs Scrapy framework to be used in his project.

I read and watched. I came to some points how to write first request spider. But I need more kind of assist.

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    plate_num = "EA66LEE"
    start_urls = [
        f'https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto='
,
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('div[@class="resultsstrip"]/a/p'):
            yield {
                'plate number': plate_num,
                'price': quote.xpath('div[@class="resultsstrip"]/a/p[@class="resultsstripprice"/text()]').get(),
            }
```

I want scrape [url](https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=EA66LEE&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=) if plate number exists then grab the

web element price tag.

```
<a id="buy_EA66LEE" class="resultsstripplate plate" href="/buy.html?plate=EA66 LEE&amp;price=999" title="Buy now">EA66 LEE                              </a>
<p class="resultsstripprice">£999</p>
```

even from terminal I cannot get the right values from xpath located  `response.xpath('div/a/p/text()').get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the base to your xpath expressions.  an xpath path should always start with `/` or `./` which represent an absolute or relative xpath path.  In your case you can get all of the prices with.

```
response.xpath('//p[@class="resultsstripprice"]/text()').getall()
```

The above path is an absolute path that looks for all `<p>` tags with a class attribute of `"resultsstripprice"` and extracts the text contents of the tag.

[This page](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) is a good resource/reference for `xpath` syntax and notation.